# Получение списка видеозаписей из группы ВКонтакте

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

[video.get](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=video.get)

Не могу найти рабочий пример получения списка видеозаписей из группы ВКонтакте. Пробовала код из данной [статьи](http://flapps.ru/forum/topic3289.html), он не работает.

Вот, что выводит консоль Google Chrome:

> <> Uncaught Error: Wrong window.name property. xd_connection.js:101
>
> >w.fastXDM.Client xd_connection.js:101
>
> >VK.initXDConn xd_connection.js:319
>
> >VK.init xd_connection.js:282
>
> >(anonymous function)

Люди добрые, может у кого есть рабочий пример взаимодействия с API VK на JS?
Подкиньте, пожалуйста...

Comment: В указаном скрипте адрес либы на старом домене.
Попробуйте http://vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2

Comment: Бесполезно...Есть более новая библиотека 
http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?52
Но и с ней ошибки

Uncaught VK.init() called without an apiId openapi.js:328
VK.init openapi.js:328
(anonymous function) 123.html:27
p.Callbacks.k jquery.min.js:2
p.Callbacks.l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочего примера нет, но исходя из описания ошибки можно догадаться, что вы не передали apiId в функцию инициализации openapi.

> Для подключения Вашего сайта к платформе Open API, необходимо выполнить следующие действия:
>
> Необходимо создать новое или взять уже созданное приложение.
>
> На странице редактирования настроек приложения заполнить необходимые поля Open API:
>
> ```
>    Open API URL – адрес сайта, к которому Вы планируте подключить Open API (например http://durov.at/)
>    Базовый домен – базовый домен Вашего сайта (например, durov.at)
> ```

Посмотрите исходный текст [этого сайта](http://durov.at/), там легко понять, как делается авторизация. Затем [входите в систему](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=VK.Auth) - на вышеприведённом сайте это тоже есть. Потом [вызываете](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=VK.Api) метод [video.get](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=video.get), в котором указываете

> id группы, видеозаписи которой нужно вернуть.

и к вам приходит информация о видео в json формате.

[Пример авторизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/100290/javascript-open-api-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5) и получения информации о [@Георгии Липартелиани](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6056/)

Comment: С авторизайией разобралась, только вот не могу получить видео

VK.Api.call('video.get', {videos: -4363_136089719,13245770_137352259}, function(r) {
  if(r.title) {
    alert(r.title);
  }
});

А вот этот код работает отлично.

Comment: `video.get` возвращает массив. Так что надо `r.response[1].title`

Comment: При таком коде

VK.Api.call('video.get', {videos: '73685822_162746010'}, function(r) {
  if(r.response[1].title) {
    alert(r.response[1].title);
  }
});

Консоль пишет Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: `console.log(r.response);` в обработчике. Или в Firebug посмотрите ответ сервера.

Comment: ReferenceError: r is not defined

Comment: к сожалению нет под рукой инструмента чтобы проверить